# could not create /home/user/.ssh directory error

Tags: ssh, telnet

i am doing telnet to a windows pc and from the telnetted pc i am doing ssh but "could not create /home/user/.ssh directory" error pops up

```
steps:

    *=================================================
    Microsoft Telnet Server.
    *=================================================
    C:\Users\vish>ssh user@192.168.100.85
    Could not create directory '/home/user/.ssh'.
```

my setup

```
    telnet        ssh   
pc1-----------pc2---------pc3
```

pls help!!!!